# How to speed up MySQL queries in real-time app

Tags: mysql, bigdata

I've created a shiny app that renders plots, tables and maps by querying in real-time a MySQL database. Since we talk about big data (i.e. 12 million rows), queries take a long time to execute, both in SQL and Spark (using scala and python).
Do you have any suggestions in order to speed up these queries? I've been thinking about switching to Cassandra, but data migration from a relational to a NoSQL DB is challenging ...

**Database background**: Data about vehicle detection in a given timestamp and a given Bluetooth station. There are two tables: one for the position and the name of stations and one with timestamp, station and number of vehicles.

An example of a query I have is the following, where I group by month to acquire the total number of vehicles detected in each month.

```
SELECT MONTH(timestamp) as month,SUM(count) as c
FROM bluetoothstations.measurement
GROUP BY month(timestamp);
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The data does not change once it is inserted, correct?  In that case, augment a "summary table" nightly (or as data is `INSERTed`).  Then the summary table will allow for a much faster generation of the `COUNT` (or other aggregates).

More discussion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables

Comment: Thank you so much! I actually tried this solution today and it speeds up the entire application. Then I used some triggers to update them.

Comment: Yeah, it "speeds up everything" by making these queries less invasive.

Answer (score 0):

I think that `MONTH(timestamp)` is causing a full table scan. My guess is that if you saved `MONTH(timestamp)` as a separate column in bluetoothstations.measurement called, say,  `month` and then added an index on `month`, then you could run

```
SELECT month,SUM(count) as c
FROM bluetoothstations.measurement
GROUP BY month;
```

which I would expect to run faster.

Use `DESCRIBE` (aka `EXPLAIN`) to get the execution plan of your query; that should give you a better idea of what's slowing down your query, and where you need indexes.

Comment: This approach turns a full _table_ scan into a full _index_ scan.  That may help some, but not necessarily a lot.

Comment: Agreed. The query, as written, is going to have to hit 12 million of *something*, and that isn't going to be fast. Using a summary table would definitely be better.

Comment: I've thought about this option, but firstly I should change the already automated script that inserts new data into the db and secondly it adds redundancy to the main table without bringing actual advantages. I mean, I should do the same for weekday and hour. Thank you for your suggestion however :)